# MySQL logic: different result for Stored Procedure vs Query with just body of Proceduce

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Ok so my stored procedure is reading variables wrong in its MySQL query. The results I need are obtained fine when I just use the body of the proc. I would like to make this a stored procedure.

Here is the SP in SQLyog:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getcusbyzip`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`@`%` PROCEDURE `getcusbyzip`(IN zipcode VARCHAR(30), IN         radius VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

SELECT C.CustomerName, C.MenuId
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ZIPCODE, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( (
SELECT Z.LAT
FROM ZipCodes Z
WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( (

  SELECT Z.LNG
  FROM ZipCodes Z
  WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
  LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( (

SELECT Z.LAT
FROM ZipCodes Z
WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM ZipCodes
HAVING distance <radius
ORDER BY distance
) AS RelevantCodes ON ( C.ZIPCODE = RelevantCodes.ZIPCODE );

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now there is only 1 record that should be returned because I have only 1 customer added for now until I get this type issue resolved. Here is where I have a breakthrough (please don't laugh, I am new to SQL entirely :) ).

I have tried changing the TYPE as well for the parameters. The zipcode broke after I changed it to an INT and I used this:

```
CALL getcusbyzip(08361,50)
```

and my resulting rows were all the rows in which "8361" were in the zipcode. Basically that is my only personal explanation as to why I received so many rows back.

When I use this with both params set to VARCHAR type:

```
CALL getcusbyzip(08361,50)
```

or

```
CALL getcusbyzip('08361',50)
```

or

```
CALL getcusbyzip(08361,'50')
```

you get the point.

I get 0 rows back when I should be getting 1 row back.

So now I think Iknow what my problem is and I might actually ask it hopefully. What is causing my SP to read the input differently as a parameter than as if I just did a query and manually put the parameters into the query. Secondly how can I adjust my procedure so that the MySQL server reads my procedure just like my Query but with the parameters ofcoarse?

Below is the query that works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT C.CustomerName, C.MenuId
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN (
SELECT ZIPCODE, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( (
SELECT Z.LAT
FROM ZipCodes Z
WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =08360
LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( (

  SELECT Z.LNG
  FROM ZipCodes Z
  WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =08360
  LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( (

SELECT Z.LAT
FROM ZipCodes Z
WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =08360
LIMIT 0 , 1
) ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM ZipCodes
HAVING distance <50
ORDER BY distance
) AS RelevantCodes ON ( C.ZIPCODE = RelevantCodes.ZIPCODE )
```

EDIT:

Another point to note is that when I change the variables to direct information in the SP(Stored Procedure) that does not fix it either so it has to be something I missing in MySQL procedure logic. I honestly do not understand why the results are different just because its in a stored procedure.

Comment: `CALL getcusbyzip('08361',50)` works fine for me

Comment: did you recreate the setup? Should I post sample table names? I have no clue why it is giving me mixed results.

Comment: Yes I did. I created the test tables, and ran the function and the stored procedure.
You can try changing the declaration to `getcusbyzip(IN zipcode VARCHAR(30), IN radius INT)` instead of `getcusbyzip(IN zipcode VARCHAR(30), IN radius VARCHAR(30))`

Comment: I had already tried that one thinking the same thing that the type was the problem. I can not test it in PHPMyadmin but I tested the call through my PHP api using POSTMAN. I also tested it with SQLyog.

Comment: I did not figure this out yet. I am just not using a stored procedure at the moment. I cannot for the life of me figure it out. the last time I checked godaddy uses 5.0.

Comment: I checked my tables so you have more information. all of my fields are VarChar, most are of the same length but not all. were you using all the same length? it is server version 5.0.96 if that makes a difference. can you post your SQL so I can run it my end and see if I get the same results you did?